# how to add data string in .plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I want put data string (for example loop for that create many url) in plist file on xcode.
this is my code (loop)

```
int count = 5;
NSString *a;
NSMutableArray *b = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];

 for (int i=1; i<= count; i++ ) {

        a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.114:81/book.php?page=%d",i];
        [b addObject:a];

    }
```

now I want save any page from top code in one row of .plist file but I dont know what can I do?

you can guidance me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure quite what you're shooting for, but if you're trying to extract the HTML from those URL strings, you could probably do something like:

```
// build path for filename

NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

// create array of html results

NSMutableArray *htmlResults = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *urlString in b)
{
    // get the html for this URL

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    // add the html to our array (or zero length string if it failed)

    if (html)
        [htmlResults addObject:html];
    else
        [htmlResults addObject:@""];
}

// save the html results to plist

[htmlResults writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

A couple of thoughts:

1. Depending upon how many pages there are, I'm not sure if I'm crazy about loading all of the pages into a plist. I'd either

   - use some persistent storage like Core Data so I didn't have to hold all of the pages in memory, or
   - do some lazy loading of the HTML (load it as I need it))
2. Also, if I was going to load all of the pages, given that it could take a little time, I might have a progress view that I update with my progress, so the user wouldn't be looking at a frozen screen while the download was in progress.
3. If you just want to retrieve a single html file, then storing that in a plist might not make sense. I'd just write the html to a file (a HTML file, not a plist).
4. I wouldn't generally like to load the html in the main queue. I'd do a `dispatch_async` to perform this in a background queue. But I hesitate to go to far until you clarify precisely what you're looking for.

But hopefully this points you in the right direction, showing you how to retrieve data from the web pages.

---

If you wanted to save the individual html files to some local file (say `X.html` where `X` is the zero-based index number), you could do something like:

```
// identify the documents folder

NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

// save the html results to local files

[b enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    if (html)
    {
        NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.html", idx]];
        [html writeToFile:filename atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[b writeToFile:@"myFile.plist" atomically:YES];`, but make sure all the data in your array are representable in a plist.